# Centering Navigation Dots in Beamer Under Section Titles

Tags: beamer, sectioning, navigation, beamer-metropolis

I've been modifying a custom Beamer template called [Metropolis](https://github.com/matze/mtheme) by trying to add the navigation dots to the top of each slide. However, the dots are not appearing centered below the text. [image]

Anyone know how to fix this? I've tried the solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245516/center-navigation-circle-bars-in-beamer) without success.

Here is my code:

```
% Must be Compiled with with LuaLaTeX (x2) then View the PDF to get the     Custom Font
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

% Theme Setup %
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, titleformat=smallcaps, sectionpage=none]{metropolis}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false, footline=authortitle]{miniframes} 


% Packages %
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.75}


% Code to Add Navigation Dots to the Default Metropolis Theme %
% This section removes the navigation dot for the title page
\makeatletter
\let\old@beamer@writeslidentry\beamer@writeslidentry
\def\beamer@writeslidentry{%
\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{}
{%else
\clearpage\beamer@notesactions%
 }
}
\makeatother

% This section adds the navigation dots for all slides
\usepackage{remreset}% tiny package containing just the \@removefromreset command

\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Off-topic comment: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` in a beamer document, beamer already does this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31483/mini-frame-navigation-not-drawn-correctly?rq=1). Adding this code fixed it:

```
\usepackage{remreset}% tiny package containing just the \@removefromreset command
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{subsection}{section}
\beamer@compresstrue # THIS LINE FIXED THE ISSUE
\makeatother
\setcounter{subsection}{1}
```